# ComboBox/ListBox - an undocumented feature?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Today, thanks to a typing mistake, I've managed to produce the following xaml:

```
<ListView>
    first line<Button>second line</Button>the third<system:String>the fourth</system:String>
</ListView>
```

This will compile and produce a four-line list:

[image]

This also works for ListBox, ItemsControl, and ComboBox.

My question: do you know if that is documented anywhere by Microsoft? I've never seen such xaml working before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the items you are describing inherit from [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).  The [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN documentation has an example with multiple types of controls added to a ListBox very similarly to how you have your items added to your ListView.

Relevant XAML from MSDN:

> ```
> <!--Create a ListBox that contains a string, a Rectangle,
>      a Panel, and a DateTime object. These items can be accessed
>      via the Items property.-->
> <ListBox xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
>          Name="simpleListBox">
>
>   <!-- The <ListBox.Items> element is implicitly used.-->
>   This is a string in a ListBox
>
>   <sys:DateTime>2004/3/4 13:6:55</sys:DateTime>
>
>   <Rectangle Height="40" Width="40"  Fill="Blue"/>
>
>   <StackPanel Name="itemToSelect">
>     <Ellipse Height="40" Fill="Blue"/>
>     <TextBlock>Text below an Ellipse</TextBlock>
>   </StackPanel>
>
>   <TextBlock>String in a TextBlock</TextBlock>
>   <!--</ListBox.Items>-->
> </ListBox>
> ```